# Como cambio el color de fondo de un fragment desde una opción de menu de la action bar?

Tags: android-layout, android-fragment, actionbar

Necesito cambiar el color de fondo de mis tres fragments desde una de las opciones de menu de mi action bar, ya lo intente utilizando un metodo en la main activity pero no me funciona, y he intentado muchas otras cosas y nada (se me cae la app).
He aqui una porcion de mi codigo y la imagen :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    public RelativeLayout fondo,fondo2,fondo3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        fondo=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.fondo);
        fondo2=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.fondo2);
        fondo3=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.fondo3);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        Bundle datos=getIntent().getExtras();
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.cambiar_color){
            colorfondo();
            return  true;
        }else if (id == R.id.acerca_de_la_app){
                ejecutarinfo();
            return  true;
        }else if (id == R.id.acerca_del_autor){
            ejecutarautor();
            return  true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void colorfondo(){

        fondo.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        fondo2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        fondo3.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
```

[image: Menu de la action bar]

Answer (score -1):

Para cambiar el color de fondo de un `Fragment` es correcto usar `setBackgroundColor()` pero debes usarlo mediante el uso de `getView()` usando la instancia del `Fragment`, ejemplo:

```
myFragment.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Elenasys, en realidad me referi a los fragments para poder explicarme bien , pero quiero cambiar los fondos de los relative layout que estan dentro de esos fragmentos, porque intente como me dijiste pero no me funcionó